# Python - How do I format a hexadecimal number in uppercase and two digits?

Tags: python

I needed to do a hexadecimal counter.

I tried to do it this way:

```
x = 0

while(x != 10):
    print('Number '+'{0:x}'.format(int(x)))
    x = x + 1
```

The counter is working. The only problem is that the output looks like this

```
 0    5    a    f   14   19
 1    6    b   10   15   1a
 2    7    c   11   16   1b
 3    8    d   12   17   1c
 4    9    e   13   18   1d
```

and I would like it to look like this

```
00   05   0A   0F   14   19
01   06   0B   10   15   1A
02   07   0C   11   16   1B
03   08   0D   12   17   1C
04   09   0E   13   18   1D
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### TL;DR (Python 3.6+)

```
print(f'Number {x:02x}')
```

---

This is explained in the [Format specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

To get uppercase letters:

> 'x'   Hex format. Outputs the number in base 16, using lowercase letters for the digits above 9.
>
> 'X'   Hex format. Outputs the number in base 16, using uppercase letters for the digits above 9.

To get 2 digits:

> *width* is a decimal integer defining the minimum field width. If not specified, then the field width will be determined by the content.
>
> When no explicit alignment is given, preceding the width field by a zero (`'0'`) character enables sign-aware zero-padding for numeric types. This is equivalent to a *fill* character of `'0'` with an *alignment* type of `'='`.

So, you either need to set the `width` to 2, the `fill` to `0`, and the `alignment` to `=`, or, more simply, just use the special `0` prefix before the `width`.

So:

```
print('Number '+'{0:02X}'.format(int(x)))
```

---

While we're at it, this is pretty silly code.

First, `x` is already an `int`, so why call `int` on it?

```
print('Number '+'{0:02X}'.format(x))
```

Meanwhile, if the only thing you're putting in a `format` string is a single format specifier, you don't need `str.format`, just `format`:

```
print('Number ' + format(x, '02X'))
```

Or, alternatively, the whole point of `str.format` is that you can throw multiple things into one format string:

```
print('Number {:02X}'.format(x))
```

If you are using >= Python 3.6, you can use elegant f-strings:

```
print(f'Number {x:02x}')
```